# Need help for resolved error with npm start

Tags: node.js, npm, build, angular-cli, serve

I'm facing a problem recently when running :

```
ng serve --watch --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --hmr
```

or:

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```

I've got the error :

> [dispatcher]/node_modules/@ngtools/json-schema/src/schema-tree.js:392
>   throw new InvalidUpdateValue('Invalid value can only be one of these :
>   ' + this.items);
>
> Error: Invalid value can only be one of these: browser,server
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! Exit status 1

I don't understand why there is error because i don't make modification on my code, and it work before.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can i see your code ?

Comment: hi Saad, witch part of code do you need ?

Comment: proxy.conf.json
{
 "/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:4001",
  "secure": false
 }
}
This code provide from a project someone else write and i've made any change.

Comment: look at this answer, i think it's will help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592332/ng-build-prod-vs-ng-build-prod-build-optimizer-true)

Comment: it not solved, I have always same error :(

Comment: Is there a way to debug schema-tree.js and knowing where bug is ?